# Rails - Use current_user.id in ActiveRecord database query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm developing a basic photo gallery website in Rails that allows users to upload images. I'm using Devise for user authentication. My Image model has a uid field in which the current user's id is saved when an image is uploaded.

Here's the create method in the controller:

```
  def create
        @image = Image.new(image_params)
        @image.uid = current_user.id
        if @image.save
          redirect_to @image
        end
      end
```

Then in the view I would like to retrieve all images in the database for which the uid matches the current user's ID (i.e, display all of the current user's images). Right now I have:

```
<% Image.where("uid == current_user.id") do |image|%>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                    <!--<img class="img-responsive" src="<%image.image_url%>" alt="">-->
                    <%= image_tag image.image_url(:thumb) %>
                </a>
            </div>
            <% end %>
```

However, no images are being displayed, I guess because current_user.id like that is just returning nil.

Is it possible to query the ActiveRecord database using the current_user.id value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is just off for what you're trying to do:

```
<% images = Image.where("uid =?", current_user.id) %>
```

Then you can loop through images with `.each`

Comment: Excellent! I'd already tried it with a parameter but I didn't realise I'd have to assign the results to an array to loop through them. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamLazarus You don't have to assign them to an array. What Todd is showing you here is how to properly pass in the `current_user.id`. In your example, you have it hardcoded as a string, so your query is literally trying to find records where the `uid` is equal to the string `"current_user.id"`. Your current code will work fine without assigning to a variable first, as long as you `where()` arguments look like this - `"uid = ?", current_user.id` (as Todd has pointed out), or like this - `"uid = #{current_user.id}"`. Todd's is the beter way to go because it protects from SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1):

While you can simply use a parameterized query like in @toddmetheny's excellent answer there is a much better conventional *Rails way* to handle linking records to each other.

Rename the `images.uid` column `user_id`. This lets you use ActiveRecord relations with little configuration.

`uid` is also a poor name choice for a foreign key column since its a common abbreviation for [*unique identifier*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_identifier) so it violates the *principle of least suprise* - which is kind of like a nice way to say don't set a bunch of traps for whatever poor soul has to use your code.

```
class RenameImagesUidToUserId < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :images, :uid, :user_id
  end
end
```

Then setup a relationship between the two models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
end

class Image ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

This lets you do `User.find(1).images` or `Images.find(1).user`.

You would create an associated record like so:

```
def create
  @image = current_user.images.new(image_params)
  if @image.save
    redirect_to @image
  end
end
```

Then to list the images you can simply do:

```
<% current_user.images.each do |image| %>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
      <%= image_tag image.image_url(:thumb) %>
    </a>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The database doesn't need to change.  on the has_many relationship, the foreign_key can be specified.  has_many :images, foreign_key: :uid

Comment: I know very well that you can use the foreign key option, but see my note on why using `uid` as a the column name is a bad idea. Its also a good idea to follow convention over configuration unless you have a good reason.